# Trace type of error mySql PDO php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to trace the type of error that occurred while executing a query using PDO prepare and execute.

For example, if I had to insert email, Name, DOB, with the email requiring to be unique, instead of writing a special query to check if Email is already taken, I would like to trace the error that occurred and know the same.

Comment: Preventing errors is often better than fixing them.

Comment: But I would rather do it in one query instead of two?

Comment: Either way, on failure, you end up doing one query. Only when there is no email the same it will have done two queries, and the query isn't going to take long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a try/catch block around the insert query and handle the double email in the exception handler.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `mystuff` (email, name ) VALUES (:email, :name)";

try {
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':name' => $name)); 
}
catch (Exception $e)  {
  echo 'email already taken';
}
```

Of course you must configure PDO that it throws exceptions on errors.

Comment: Ya i did think of this... but wouldn't this show 'email taken' even if anything else went wrong?? Isn't there a way of checking what error took place?

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php In the catch block you can use a SWITCH to handle different error situations

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will configure your database to put a `UNIQUE KEY`

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD CONSTRAINT uniqukey_for_mail  UNIQUE(email);
```

Then you will use PDO with ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

```
$bddConnect = new PDO('dsn',$user,$password);
$bddConnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMOD,PDO::ERRMOD_EXCEPTION);
```

Then when you will update or insert datas, you will just have to wrap your query with a try/catch, and check that your error is a constraint violation

```
try{
    $bddConnect->exec("UPDATE yourtable SET email='already in table EMAIL' WHERE
   id='other id than the one that has the email'");
}catch(PDOException $e){
    if(strpos('constraint violation',$e->getMessage())!==false){
       echo "already taken";
    }
}
```

Comment: once again... but wouldn't this show 'email taken' even if anything else went wrong?? Isn't there a way of checking what error took place?